# Finding if a given quarter was present in a date range in R

Tags: r, date

I have data that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
a<-data_frame(open=as.Date(c("12-31-2016","10-28-2016","08-01-2016"),format=c("%m-%d-%Y")),close=as.Date(c("01-04-2017","01-05-2017","01-01-2017"),format=c("%m-%d-%Y")))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
open       close     
<date>     <date>    
2016-12-31 2017-01-04
2016-10-28 2017-01-05
2016-08-01 2017-01-01
```

I am attempting to create columns that reflect if a given quarter year and quarter is contained in the range between `Open` and `Close`.  Thus, in this case there are three quarters and the final data would look like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
 open       close      Q3_2016 Q4_2016 Q1_2017
<date>     <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
2016-12-31 2017-01-04      0.      1.      1.
2016-10-28 2017-01-05      0.      1.      1.
2016-08-01 2017-01-01      1.      1.      1.
```

I have tried a few different solutions, but none of them seem to be working.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also using the `lubridate` package, you could use the `int_overlaps` function:

```
library(lubridate)
a %>%
  mutate(Q3_2016=int_overlaps(interval(ymd(open),ymd(close)),interval(ymd("2016-07-01"),ymd("2016-09-30")))*1,
         Q4_2016=int_overlaps(interval(ymd(open),ymd(close)),interval(ymd("2016-10-01"),ymd("2016-12-31")))*1,
         Q1_2017=int_overlaps(interval(ymd(open),ymd(close)),interval(ymd("2017-01-01"),ymd("2017-03-31")))*1)

  open       close      Q3_2016 Q4_2016 Q1_2017
  <date>     <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2016-12-31 2017-01-04    0       1.00    1.00
2 2016-10-28 2017-01-05    0       1.00    1.00
3 2016-08-01 2017-01-01    1.00    1.00    1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DateToQuartersGen <- function(DATES){
        q1 <- as.Date("2012-10-01",  format = "%Y-%m-%d") # start of first quarter
        q2 <- as.Date("2012-01-01",  format = "%Y-%m-%d") # start of second quarter
        q3 <- as.Date("2012-04-01",  format = "%Y-%m-%d") # start of third quarter
        q4 <- as.Date("2012-07-01",  format = "%Y-%m-%d") # start of forth quarter

        # Convert dates from any year to 2012 dates
        d <- as.Date(strftime(DATES, format="2012-%m-%d"))

        ifelse(d >= q1 | d < q2, '1st Quarter',
               ifelse(d >= q2 & d < q3, '2nd Quarter',
                      ifelse(d >= q3 & d < q4, '3rd Quarter', '4th Quarter')))
}
```

you could then run this function on two separate columns that would indicate what quarter the start date is in and what quarter the end date is in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lubridate package and the interval function as :

```
Q3_2016 <- interval(ymd("2016-07-01"),ymd("2016-09-30"))
Q4_2016 <- interval(ymd("2016-10-01"),ymd("2016-12-31"))
Q1_2017 <- interval(ymd("2017-01-01"),ymd("2016-03-31"))

a %>% 
mutate(Q3_2016=ifelse(interval(ymd(open),ymd(close)) %within% Q3_2016,TRUE,FALSE)) %>%
mutate(Q4_2016=ifelse(interval(ymd(open),ymd(close)) %within% Q4_2016,TRUE,FALSE)) %>%
mutate(Q1_2017=ifelse(interval(ymd(open),ymd(close)) %within% Q1_2017,TRUE,FALSE))
```